# Ошибка при импорте пакета NuGet

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, уведомления, nuget

Всем привет, хочу использовать всплывающие уведомления в стиле Windows. Нашёл подходящую пакет, но после попытки компиляции возникает вот такая ошибка. Не понимаю что делаю не так.

Пакет NuGet: Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications
Мой проект написан на wpf

Сама ошибка

> элемент "D:\Visual studio\Folder Hiding\packages\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.4.6.0\build\net461....\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" в списке элементов "ReferencePath" не указывает значение для метаданных "CopyLocal".  Чтобы использовать эти метаданные, необходимо указать их путем задания %(ReferencePath.CopyLocal), либо все элементы в списке должны указывать значение для этих метаданных.  FFHider

Comment: UWP и WPF несовместимы

Comment: в описании пакета указана поддержка wpf

Comment: а где описание?

Comment: Файл `packages.config` имеется у проекта? Если да, у вас старый тип проекта, нажмите на файл пкм и там будет конвертация в новый. Указанный проект требует именно PackageReference

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за помощь, проблема оказалась в `packages.config` обновил до `PackageReference` и всё заработало. Ещё раз всем спасибо